# Auto matching tempo

Tags: tempo, beats

Does anyone know if there's a way to automatically adjust a recorded track to edit out early entries?
I'm putting together a collaboration video with everyone having recorded their individual parts at home and without a conductor, many people are quite far off on their entries. 
Anyone know if this is a technique that exists?

Comment: You mentioned you are making a video, do you want to edit the audio tracks only? It is doable in different ways depending on the audio software you use. I suggest mentioning the type of software you’re using so you can get specific information on how it can be done based on your DAW.

Answer (score 1):

If the parts were played to the same reference track like a click/metronome track, this should be straight-forward. Load the parts in a multitrack audio/video editor, each part on its own track, and line them up using something as the sound and/or picture. Lining up means, move each part on the timeline to the correct spot.

If the parts were not played to the same reference track and everyone has their own tempo, it's going to be much more difficult, and you'll have to use some kind of time time-stretching.